# Prevent users overwriting each others work in svn

Tags: svn, version-control

I'm using subversion for version control.

I frequently see instances where commits overwrite each other. In git this is prevented as you cannot push until you have pulled if your local repo is out of date. Is there a similar mechanism in subversion?

e.g.

1. Bob updates his working copy with svn update. He proceeds to work on some changes to file A over several days.
2. Meanwhile, Alice update her working copy, and makes a small change to file A, then commits it in the same day.
3. A day or so later, Bob commits his changes - which won't include Alice's changes to file A - overwriting and removing Alice's changes. When Bob makes his commit, he gets no warning, no conflict or any indication that he needed to update first because the repo has changed.
4. Bob does not deliberately touch any of the lines of code that Alice changed, but because his working copy does not contain Alice's code when he commits it, the result is that the repo has Bob's changes only, and Alice's have vanished.

Although Bob and Alice both have a process in place that means they are supposed to use svn update before they commit, it seems (to Bob) that svn does not enforce this and Bob frequently forgets.

How can we prevent this?

**[Edit]** Thanks to everyone who has waded in so far. It looks like you're all saying the same thing - that what I'm describing can't happen. Unfortunately my experience with svn, using different clients, and different versions of svn over several years (on and off) is exactly as described above. It looks like there's a fundamental thing I'm missing in svn to make it prevent committing code when your working copy is out of sync - it's happened too many times for me to believe that svn can prevent it, despite all the answers here. So something is screwy - I need to find out what - does anyone have any suggestions about how the perceived effect described could happen (without Bob deliberately deleting Alice's code and then lying to the world)?

**PS:** I'm Bob.

Comment: This is the basic of any version control tool. In your example, when Bob commits his changes some months later (already the same file committed by Alice) Bob must get an "Out of Date" Error, which will force Bob to update the working copy. Else commits will not be allowed.

Comment: I agree, it's a basic requirement, but it's not happening with svn. We're talking about only 1 or 2 commits between Bob updating, and Bob committing though.

Comment: >>A day or so later, Bob commits his changes - which won't include Alice's changes to file A - overwriting and removing Alice's changes.<<  This will not happen with svn. One possibility is when Bob updates the working copy, Alice's changes too comes to his working copy, and Bob removing Alice's code. :)

Comment: The technology in place to enforce that Bob updates before commit, is SVN itself. SVN will not allow Bob to commit if any of the files he is committing have been changed on the server since he last did an update.

Comment: What you're describing **can not happen** with Subversion without Bob intentionally doing something he shouldn't be doing, that he isn't telling you about.

Comment: Hi @Hippyjim - do you happen to remember what client and server and which version they are ? I know it's a stretch - but it might be helpful for me as I think I've got the same issue at the moment - some svn commits mysteriously obliterated existing changes without warning that current copy is stale.

Comment: @YS - wow, it's been years! If I recall it was various clients, including TortoiseSVN and the one built in to Netbeans, but don't ask me the versions. The server was VisualSVN, but again, no idea of the version. It was probably latest stable for both at the time of posting though. Glad I'm not the only one to experience this, honestly thought i'd lost my mind as this isn't supposed to be possible. I'd take a look at the other answers, my most likely culprit is misuse of a merge tool (though I vaguely remember there was no merge indicated, the changes simply vanished)

Comment: @Hippyjim thanks for answering. Yep - same client and server here: Tortoise+VisualSVN. I too - was suspicious of the Merge tool but then in my case: it didn't even get to the point where it picks up a conflict. Heck - it didn't even warn the dev that his working copy is stale and needs updating when he committed.

Comment: @YS - yup. Same. No warnings at all.

Answer (score 4):

> Although Bob and Alice both have a process in place that means they are supposed to use svn update before they commit, there is no technology in place to enforce this and Bob frequently forgets.

That's because there **is** no technology that can completely protect you from users not paying attention to what they're doing.

> Meanwhile, Alice update her working copy, and makes a small change to file A, then commits it in the same day.
>
> A day or so later, Bob commits his changes - which won't include Alice's changes to file A - overwriting and removing Alice's changes.

Bob can't commit without running `svn update`, and if he's changed things that Alice changed, that will trigger a conflict which Bob has to resolve. If Bob doesn't properly resolve it himself, yes, Alice's work can be lost - **but that's a "people" problem, not a technical one**. No software can stop Bob from improperly managing that code conflict.

Comment: "Bob can't commit without running svn update, and if he's changed things that Alice changed, that will trigger a conflict which Bob has to resolve." - That's the point, Bob can commit without updating first (whether he's supposed to or not, Bob is only human and sometimes makes mistakes), and Bob has, removing code that Alice just wrote. No errors, no conflicts, no warning, just a nice easy successful commit. How do I make it warn him?

Comment: @Hippyjim: Your Scenario will not work. Either the changes will successfully be merged by an (required) update or the changes are causing a conflict, either way bob cannot commit his changes and removing Alices changes without reviewing it. SVN forces him to review the changes. IF you disagree, write a small script with your scenario.

Comment: No, Hippyjim, Bob cannot commit without first updating, if he made changes to the same files as Alice. SVN won't let him. This is a very basic feature that SVN did *NOT* miss.

Answer (score 4):

> [Edit] Thanks to everyone who has waded in so far. It looks like you're all saying the same thing - that what I'm describing can't happen. Unfortunately my experience with svn, using different clients, and different versions of svn over several years (on and off) is exactly as described above. It looks like there's a fundamental thing I'm missing in svn to make it prevent committing code when your working copy is out of sync - it's happened too many times for me to believe that svn can prevent it, despite all the answers here. So something is screwy - I need to find out what - does anyone have any suggestions about how the perceived effect described could happen (without Bob deliberately deleting Alice's code and then lying to the world)?

Bob/Hippyjim,

I have this scenario occasionally with users on my team where they have this same problem and they swear they weren't warned by the tool. I am still trying to get to the bottom of it, but I am fairly confident they are doing something in a way that causes them to overwrite changes without knowing it. Here are two scenarios I see this happening:

1.) Bob checks out revision 100. Alice commits a change, revision 101. Bob attempts to commit his change and is forced to update, but now has conflicts. Bob is overwhelmed by the conflicts and makes one of these mistakes:

...1.a.) Before updating, Bob had copied a back-up of his changed file and now copies it back into his working copy.

...1.b.) Bob selects "Use this whole file" in the merge tool, on his version, without actually considering the conflicts.

...1.c.) Bob manually modifies the working copy file and manually deletes the unified diff text that the tool put into the file.

2.) Bob is working on source code in two locations. One location is tied to SVN, one maybe isn't (could be web based, on another computer, or in another folder)--or maybe it is a working copy of a different branch/repository. Sometimes the changes are made in the OTHER location. Bob updates his primary working copy like a good boy. Bob realized he's made changes on file A in one of these other sources. He copies and pastes the file into his working copy and commits.

Either way, these are training issues and are caused by bad practices.

As for (1.): not understanding the merging and conflict resolution can cause these scenarios.

As for (2.): Copy and pasting is a bad idea unless you are very careful when working with SCM. The system doesn't know whether you copied and pasted old changes or intentionally typed all those old changes in manually. Making copies or backups of files is also asking for trouble (copying a file and creating a '.bak' version is something I see "Old School" developers do sometimes)--and shouldn't really be necessary since the SCM system shouldn't allow you to lose your code. If you fail to use the tool-provided merge tools, you can fool the tool into allowing you to overwrite old changes.

These are the scenarios I have seen in inexperienced developers. Even great developers sometimes struggle with complex conflict resolution.

One final thought... what SVN client do you use? I am not aware of any that would fail to warn about a stale working copy (like the other commenters). I have worked extensively with command-line SVN on Linux and SlikSVN  and TortoiseSVN on Windows.

Comment: Nice thoughts, unfortunately this happened without any merges that I'm aware of, and Bob is definitely only using one location for his files. Of course since I wrote this question I've been unable to reproduce the problem, so it's been hard to follow up. I'll keep an eye out for the first scenario you mentioned as it does seem the more likely of the two.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still confused by your scenario.

> Bob updates his working copy with svn update. He proceeds to work on some changes to file A over several days.

Bob updates, we'll assume a clean working copy, and makes changes to File "A". Understand. For argument sake, let's say Bob's working copy is based upon Revision #100.

> Meanwhile, Alice update her working copy, and makes a small change to file A, then commits it in the same day.

Okay, Alice updates to Revision 100, and made her change. She commits revision #101.

> A day or so later, Bob commits his changes - which won't include Alice's changes to file A - overwriting and removing Alice's changes. When Bob makes his commit, he gets no warning, no conflict or any indication that he needed to update first because the repo has changed.

Okay, you've lost me here. Bob's working copy is based upon Revision 100. However, the most recent revision for this working directory would be Revision 101. Bob can't commit unless Bob updates to revision 101 first.

Having to update before you do your commit is a big, hulking clue stick striking the developer right on the kisser. It is a warning that your path is fraught with danger: Someone else is working on the same thing you are. Beware! Beware!

At that point, Bob should have done an `svn log` to see what was being changed and why. Maybe Alice was fixing the same bug that Bob was working on. Maybe Alice was working on a slightly different bug. Bob should have been able to see that Alice changed File A at that point, and even what lines she changed.

Still, Bob would need to do an update, and Bob would have seen File A was Merged and not simply updated. That's a Lost In Space Robot Danger Will Robinson type of warning.

This is very difficult to ignore, especially if Alice changed a line that Bob was working on. That would have resulted in a merge conflict. This is the Reactor Core Overheating  - Explosion is Immanent. Sure Bob could ignore that warning. They did so at Chernobyl too.

Bob could have manually reverted Alice's line. Or, if a merge was needed, simply used his revision to overwrite Alice's changes. This isn't done by accident.

There's nothing that prevents Bob from reverting changes. Bob could go through the entire Subversion log and remove all of Alice's commits. There's no version control system that doesn't prevent users from removing changes. If a change is bad, you want to revert it.

---

Maybe the problem is that Bob was making some very delicate changes in File A. Maybe File A is an icon or gif that Bob is painstakingly modifying. Bob's an artist. Alice's changes simply would cause problems with what Bob was doing.

If that's the case, Bob can *lock* File A. In Subversion file locking is usually advisory. However, when Alice wants to make her change, she'll see File A is locked, and that Bob has a lock on it. Bob can even give a lock comment.

This would have been Alice's indication that she has to work closely with Bob on the change. However if Bob decides to go to Bermuda for two weeks, Alice can *steal* the lock and still make her changes.